# Python: Move files from one location to other based on partial file name and modified date

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and need help.   I have files in Folder with different names and extensions.  I'm trying to move these files to Destination folder based on key word "EOM" in the file name and modified file date within last 24 hours.  My code below moves all file to Destination folder.  I need help to filter out only files with "EOM" name in it.  Please help.  Thank you.

File names:
test.txt
Nov_EOM_12_11.csv
Dec_EOM_12_12.csv
other_EOM.csv

```
src = 'e:/folder'
dst = r'e:/foder/Destination'

now = time.time()
SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60
before = now - SECONDS_IN_DAY

def last_mod_time(fname):
    return os.path.getmtime(fname)

for fname in os.listdir(src):    
    src_fname = os.path.join(src, fname)
        if (last_mod_time(src_fname) > before):
        dst_fname = os.path.join(dst, fname)
        shutil.move(src_fname, dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (last_mod_time(src_fname) > before) and "EOM" in fname:
```